# Django edit button redirects to create form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-urls

My Django edit button always redirects to my Create form and creates a new record. I want an edit function that allows me to edit an existing record. No idea why it keeps returning the create form instead!

home.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% for task in tasks %}
  <div class="row pt-3">
      <h1>{{ task.title }}</h1>
      <br>
      <p>{{ task.pub_date_pretty }}</p>
      <br>
      <p>{{ task.summary }}</p>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>{{ task.user }}</p>
      <br>
      <br>
  </div>
  <div class="row pt-3">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'edit' task.id %}">Edit</a>
  </div>
{% endfor %}

<br>
<br>

<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'create' %}">Create</a>

{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    from .models import Task
    from django.utils import timezone

    def home(request):
        tasks = Task.objects
        return render(request, 'home/home.html', {'tasks': Task.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')})

    def taskdetail(request, task_id):
        task = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=task_id)
        return render(request, 'home/taskdetail.html', {'task':task})

    @login_required
    def create(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            if request.POST['title'] and request.POST['description']:
                task = Task()
                task.title = request.POST['title']
                task.description = request.POST['description']
                task.pub_date = timezone.datetime.now()
                task.completed = False
                task.user = request.user
                task.save()
                return render(request, 'home/taskdetail.html', {'task':task})

            else:
                return render(request, 'home/create.html', {'error':'All fields are required'})
        else:
            return render(request, 'home/create.html')

    @login_required
    def edit(request, task_id):
        if request.method == "POST":
            if request.POST['title'] and request.POST['description']:
                task = Task(pk=task_id)
                task.title = request.POST['title']
                task.description = request.POST['description']
                task.pub_date = timezone.datetime.now()
                task.completed = False
                task.user = request.user
                task.save(pk=task_id)
                return render(request, 'home/taskdetail.html', {'task':task})

            else:
                return render(request, 'home/create.html', {'error':'All fields are required'})
        else:
            return render(request, 'home/create.html')

    @login_required(login_url="/accounts/signup")
    def delete(request, task_id):
        if request.method == "POST":
            task = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=task_id)
            task.delete()
            return render(request, 'home', {'task':task})
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('create', views.create, name='create'),
        path('<int:task_id>', views.taskdetail, name='taskdetail'),
        path('edit/<int:task_id>', views.edit, name='edit'),
        path('delete/<int:task_id>', views.delete, name='delete'),
    ]
```

I reset the server a number of times and cleared the browser cache, but

I have no idea why it doesn't send me to my edit view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in `edit` function: `return render(request, 'home/create.html')`

When you open the page, it's a `GET` request by default so it goes to this line. You should render the edit page. And, it's better to use forms to handle the data in the function.

Answer (score 1):

When you copied your `edit()` method, you forgot to change the template names at the bottom.

```
return render(request, 'home/create.html')
```